# How to exit the current part of for loop when condition is met

Tags: pandas, for-loop, if-statement

I want to be be able to loop through a pandas dataframe that has a column that has the day number (1-31) (column called day) and a column called 'checked_day' which checks if the column day is an integer or not (True or False is the boolean. In a new column called 'Flag' I want to first check if it is an integer and if it is not then it is marked 'Fail', if it is we then check the value of the integer and return a result.

In the test dataset I am working with there is one row of the 'day' column which is a string and therefore should return 'Fail'. The code fails as it also checks the subsequent condition also. I want to exit the current iteration of the loop and continue through the next rows. Any help appreciated. thanks

```
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    if df.loc[index, 'checked_day'] ==False:
        df.loc[index, 'Flag'] = 'Fail'
        continue
    elif (df['day'].astype(int) >=1) and (df['day'].astype(int) <=31):
        df.loc[index, 'Flag']='Valid Day'
    else:
        df.loc[index, 'Flag']='0'
    
df.head()
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use `continue` to skip the current iteration.

Comment: I've tried that already and it doesn't work. it still always checks the second if statement, which i feel is strange

Comment: Then your if statement seems not working as intended. Are you sure the continue is being executed? Also what is the result inside the 'checked_day' column you got from the string?

Comment: Its not working properly anyway. The indentation is correct - when changing it i get an error. Is there anything else to look out for. Day is a string for one row as mentioned and this is the row that returns as the error. does the for firstly scan the whole loop and perhaps something like a datatype issue might mean it is not processed at all?

Comment: What is being displayed in the row with the string and the column 'checked_day'?

Comment: Checked_day is equal to False as it is not an integer so the first if condition is satisfied and it should exit with a continue but doesn't. if i remove the second if statement the loop acts as it should, returning 'Fail' for that row and '0' for the rest.

Comment: Try to make the second if and the else to a elif, that should fix your problem, because at the end of the loop it's checking if the day is valid and if not executing the else statement (A string is not considered valid)

Comment: I adjusted the second if to check that but it makes no difference - same error. Not sure that makes sense anyway as surely the continue should skip what follows. The final else can't be an elif as it is a catch all for the remainder and i don't have a condition for that

Comment: I don't know why the continue isn't working here, but you could use:                             
if (df['day'].astype(int) <=1) and (df['day'].astype(int) >=31)::                                                 as a catch for the remainder

Comment: that is the same code i had to begin with so that won't work. hopefully someone else will chime in. thanks. strange behaviour on the continue statement

Comment: No it isn't, I flipped the < signs, so that days between 1 and 31 are gonna be excluded. You should replace the else statement with this line.

Comment: you can't put a check like that in an else statement it has to be elif. an else statement can only return a value.

Comment: I wrote, that you should >>replace<< the else with the if statement

Comment: all the `continue` statements are redundants.
Please provide a working example of the code